# Sort List inside Map in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In this endpoint http://www.caguascriollos.com/nuevaweb/wp-json/sportspress/v2/tables I'm getting a List of Maps.
Inside each element, in the "data" key, I have another List. That List have a "pos" (position) key.

I want to sort each "data" depending on the "pos" value, but I'm getting the following error:

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'sort'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:6
Tried calling: sort(LinkedHashSet len:1))
```

My code:

```
 final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://www.caguascriollos.com/nuevaweb/wp-json/sportspress/v2/tables'));
_positions = json.decode(response.body);

for (var _position in _positions!) {
  _position['data'].sort({
    (a,b) => {
      if (a.isInt() && b.isInt()) {
        a.toInt().compareTo(b.toInt())
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs obtain the `data` element and isolate it.
You can convert your `data` map entries to a list and then compare by `pos`, for example:

```
// Data looks like this:
// final data = {"0": {"pos": 1}, "5394": {"pos": 2}, "5395": {"pos": 0}};

// Convert dictionary entries to list
final l = data.entries.toList();
// Sort by the value of pos
l.sort((e1, e2) => Comparable.compare(e1.value["pos"]!, e2.value["pos"]!));
// l is sorted by pos
print(l);
```

This is just a prototype. You need to make sure there are no null `pos`s and that data types are the expected.